# iOS freezed UI without error logs

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, uicollectionview

I have an issue on my swift iOS app and i'm not able to understand which is the real problem. I have a UITabBarController with five UINavigationControllers on each tab. Main content of these controllers are UICollectionView filled dynamically from a WebService with custom UICollectionViewCells (about 30 for each CollectionView) with custom UIImageViews, custom UILabels and custom UIButtons loaded from custom xib files.

When i push few controllers all is working good (CollectionViews become a bit slower but i think it's normal for memory usage) but when a NavigationController contains 6 or 7 controllers and i try to scroll down, my UI is freezed, the app doesn't crash and i don't receive any kind of runtime error. I can still exit using Home button but the app is completely locked.

I'm dequeuing every cell in every collectionView with identifier and i'm using this attributes in every custom cell for performance:

```
layer.shouldRasterize = true
layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen().scale
```

***What i tried***

1. Debug views too see if some UIWindow or UIView is covering the controller view
2. Stop image loading and show blank imageViews
3. Clear code used in UICollectionView scroll delegate methods

But the issue is always reproducible on 6th or 7th controller, making some stress test. I gave a look to FPS too, but values are always from 40 to 60 that seems good. CPU usage is always very high, 90/100 % but method didReceiveMemoryWarning is never fired.

My goal would be that my app could push many controllers without freezing or become very very slow, but i can't understand what i'm missing.

Comment: When the app freezes, use the debugger to pause it.  Look at a stack trace for the main thread to see what it's doing.

Comment: I don't know where to put breakpoint since freezing is random. I tried in app delegate, but i don't know if stack trace can be compromised in that moment.

Comment: You don't need a breakpoint.  Just click the "pause" button in the debug controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Philip Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784753/phillip-mills)

Issue is that i was calling this code in my custom UICollectionViewCell setup:

```
func rotateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, indeterminate: Bool) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, CGFloat(M_PI))

        }, completion: { finished -> Void in

            if indeterminate {
                self.rotateWithDuration(duration, indeterminate: indeterminate)
            }
    })
}
```

View rotation animation was running indefinitely in every cell, so the CPU was a bit sweat.